# Apex query optimization

Tags: select, salesforce, query-optimization, apex, soql

I am trying this query:

```
List<Account> onlyRRCustomer = [SELECT
                                   ac.rr_First_Name__c,
                                   ac.rr_Last_Name__c,
                                   ac.rr_National_Insurance_Number__c,
                                   ac.id,
                                   ac.rr_Date_of_Birth__c
                               FROM
                                   Account ac
                               WHERE
                                   ac.rr_National_Insurance_Number__c IN :uniqueNiInputSet
                                   AND RecordTypeId  = :recordTypeId];
```

It gives me an error:

> SELECT ac.rr_First_Name__c, ac.rr_Last_Name__c,
>   ac.rr_National_Insurance_Number__c, ac.id, ac.rr_Date_of_Birth__c FROM
>   Account ac WHERE (ac.rr_National_Insurance_Number__c = :tmpVar1 AND
>   RecordTypeId = :tmpVar2) 10:12:05.0
>   (11489528)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[49]|System.QueryException: Non-selective
>   query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an
>   indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.

I understand uniqueNiInputSet.size() ~ 50, so, it's not an issue but for that record type, it might contains more records.

So, if i changed the position will that work? Means, first the recordtype and then the NIset in where clause. Is there any order how where clause are selected in SF. So, it will only look for 50 member and then within 50 it will serach for the particular record type?

Answer (score 0):

That just means that the script is taking too long to execute.  You may need to move this to a @future method or make execute it using Database.Batchable.

I don't think the order matters in SOQL, I think it's just trying to return too many records.

Answer (score 0):

A non-selective query means you are performing a query against a table that has a large number of records and your query is not specific enough.  You can work with Salesforce support to try to resolve this, either through the creation of additional backend indexes or by making the query more selective.
To be honest, your query looks very selective already, you're not using LIKE or IN.  You should also put your most selective conditions first (resulting in a more focused query against your records).
I know it should'nt matter, but I would also move your conditions out of the parenthesis.
If there are any other fields you can filter on, that may help.  Sometimes, you have to actually create new fields and populate them just to help make your queries more selective.
Also, if rr_National_Insurance_Number__c is a formula field, you will want to change it to a text field and populate workflow or apex instead.  Formula fields require additional time on the servers to calculate.

```
SELECT rr_First_Name__c, rr_Last_Name__c, rr_National_Insurance_Number__c, id, rr_Date_of_Birth__c 
FROM Account
WHERE new_custom_field__c = TRUE 
AND rr_National_Insurance_Number__c = :tmpVar1
AND RecordTypeId = :tmpVar2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is non-selective. For a standard indexes is 30% for the fist million records and 15% of records over a million up to 1 million records total.  For and "AND" query each individual  where criteria must itself be selective see [this](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf) quick reference cheat sheet.   In general try making

> rr_National_Insurance_Number__c

an external id which will make it an indexed by salesforce by default and retry you query.  Record Types are already indexed by default.  If the result is still non-selective because of the number of results returned, try limiting the number of results using a field like CreatedDate to limit the scope of the query.